# div returns empty while scraping price using BeautifulSoup , everything else like title, picture links returns a value.Why is this happening?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need the product's price. I go the title, image link. I want to know why is div returning empty , when the div isn't ?

```
import requests, bs4, math
import urllib.request

res = requests.get('https://www.zara.com/ca/en/turtleneck-sweater-p07148300.html?v1=8389726&v2=1179974', 

headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'})

zara = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

price = zara.find('div', attrs={'class':"price _product-price"})

print(price)`
```

returns

```html
<div class="price _product-price" data-qa-qualifier="product-price" tabindex="0"> </div>
```

Where the div has

```html
<div class="price _product-price" tabindex="0" data-qa-qualifier="product-price">
<span>49.90 CAD</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION 1:**

The table is generated by Javascript but in the page source there are JSON data for that table.

To get the data you can use BeautifulSoup and json. I also used regex too and included more of the data. This will iterate through each product, but if you're noticing no price change between the sizes/skus, just take the first instance instead of iterating.

```
import requests
import bs4
import json
import re

res = requests.get('https://www.zara.com/ca/en/turtleneck-sweater-p07148300.html?v1=8389726&v2=1179974', 
headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'})

zara = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

scripts = zara.find_all('script')
jsonObj = None

for script in scripts:
    if '@context' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

for product in jsonObj:
    name = product['name']
    sku = product['sku']
    price = product['offers']['price']
    availabililty = product['offers']['availability'].split('/')[-1]
    availabililty = [s for s in re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", availabililty) if s]
    availabililty = ' '.join(availabililty)

    print('Name: %s   SKU: %s   Price: %0.2f  Availability: %s' %(name, sku, float(price), availabililty))
```

**Output:**

```
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-809-3   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-809-4   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-809-5   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-809-6   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-250-3   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-250-4   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-250-5   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-250-6   Price: 49.90  Availability: Out Of Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-401-3   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-401-4   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-401-5   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-401-6   Price: 49.90  Availability: Out Of Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-800-3   Price: 49.90  Availability: Out Of Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-800-4   Price: 49.90  Availability: In Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-800-5   Price: 49.90  Availability: Out Of Stock
Name: TURTLENECK SWEATER   SKU: 8389726-800-6   Price: 49.90  Availability: Out Of Stock
```

**OPTION 2:**

Since the page is dynamic, use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to simulate opening a browser, letting the page render, then grab the html.

```
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver 

url = 'https://www.zara.com/ca/en/turtleneck-sweater-p07148300.html?v1=8389726&v2=1179974'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

res = browser.page_source
zara = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')  

price = zara.find('div', attrs={'class':"price _product-price"})

print(price)

browser.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print(price)
<div class="price _product-price" data-qa-qualifier="product-price" tabindex="0"><span>49.90 CAD</span></div>
```

or to get just the price without tags:

```
print(price.text)
49.90 CAD
```

**OPTION 3:**

Use the package [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/) 
It appears it can grab some text that’s rendered by JavaScript, but I've never used it as it conflicts with jupyter Notebooks and Spyder which I use regularly, so I get errors (and I've been fine with using Selenium in the past). So you'd be on your own to try that, but below is an example from the docs.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('http://python-requests.org/')

r.html.render()

r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')['months']
```

**Output:**

```
'<time>25</time>'
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: What if it's a discounted one ? Like this
 
https://www.zara.com/ca/en/contrasting-sneakers-p15320302.html?v1=6453674&v2=1166591

How can I get the old price from the scripts ?

Comment: sure. give me a second. would you mind posting it as a new question?

Comment: thats stored in another json object. if you post as a new question within the next few minutes, I can post the answer, otherwise, won't be able to until later

Comment: I guess I'll give it a try. If I can't , I'll post it as a question. Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you do it the way I have posted with Selenium, the old price will be right next to the new price with the span tags. If you do it the json Object, its a little trickier, but I worked that way as well.